# Delphi Tokyo language exception

Tags: delphi-10.2-tokyo

During a debugging session, I have, by mistake, checked "ignore exceptions of this type".

Via the menu "Tools" -> "Options" -> "language exceptions", there is a way to remove an exception from the list, but when I remove it and validate, I got the following error:

> "Interface not supported"

Does anyone have an idea, how to fix this or how to workaround?

After more research, i found the problem, it is not Delphi, it is CnWizards or Gexperts, after removing the 2 of them, i was able to remove the exception language without crash!

Comment: You can try to delete it manually from the registry using RegEdit. You'll find the ignored exceptions in `HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\19.0\Debugging\Embarcadero Debuggers\Language Exception Classes`

Comment: Tnx Ken, exactly the entry i was looking for!